# How can I highlight a reference in the reference section?

Tags: bibliographies, tcolorbox, highlighting

I would like to highlight a new reference in the reference section of my paper.
The following code works to change the reference text color into red. 
How can I modify the command to include the highlight (\hl{...}) instead of the text color?

Thank you very much in advance!

```
\usepackage{xcolor,cite,etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\pretocmd\@bibitem{\color{black}\csname keycolor#1\endcsname}{}{\fail}
\newcommand\citecolor[1]{\@namedef{keycolor#1}{\color{red}}}
\makeatother
\citecolor{ref_to_be_colored_in_red}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref_to_be_colored_in_red}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61229757/1968828